# Как в gimp определить шрифт?

Tags: графика

Файл psd. Текст в слое не выделить при нажатии на букву А. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить шрифт. Фотошопа нет.
UDP: насчёт photopea - она не видит моего файла и шрифтов [image: photopea не видит мой файл]

Comment: https://www.photopea.com/

Comment: посмотрите, пожалуйста, апдейт к записи

Comment: если бы вы выложили файл или скриншот шансов получить ответ было бы больше

Comment: я понимаю, но не уверена, что заказчик к этому хорошо отнесётся.